# Ember.js , HighCharts - accessing JSON data from controller

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ember.js, highcharts

I need to access JSON data from model, i used "this.model" in controller. From what i see in console log "this.model" is returning array of data arrays.

```
  App.CardsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
 return Ember.$.getJSON('/cards');
}
});
```

This is what is server on path /cards returning :

```
[[1317888000000,372.5101],[1317888060000,372.4]]
```

I want to use that data in my ember HighStock (from HighCharts) implementation. It's drawing chart with this manually entered data:

```
  App.CardsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    series: [{
           name : 'test',
                type: 'area',
                data :[[1317888000000,372.5101],[1317888060000,372.4]],
```

...

But not drawing with this:

```
App.CardsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
series: [{
                name : 'test',
                type: 'area',
                data : this.model,
...
```

From what i see in console, this.model is returning not only array with arrays of data but other ember specific objects too, is that the problem? if yes then how to access only JSON returned data so i can use it in controller?

Comment: shouldn't it be `this.get('model')` in your second controller snippet? as opposed to `this.model`?

Comment: I've started with "this.get('model')" but with it iam getting "Uncaught Type error: Undefined is not a function"

Comment: Can you show the output for `console.log(this.model)` ?

Comment: [Array[2], Array[2], __nextSuper: undefined, __ember_meta__: Object, __ember1409946321702: "ember410", _super: function, nextObject: function…]
0: Array[2]
0: 1317888000000
1: 372.5101
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
1: Array[2]
0: 1317888060000
1: 372.4
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
__ember1409946321702: "ember410"
__ember_meta__: Object
__nextSuper: undefined
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: could you please create a http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ fiddle where we can see the actual issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly format the data in your router itself, after the promise is successful.

When the controller is initialized, this method also will run once and will intialise.
To setup the data from the controller itself, format the data after the json promise is successful.
Ex:

```
 App.CardsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
   return Ember.$.getJSON('/cards');
   }.then(function(data){
     return [{
           name : 'test',
           type: 'area',
           data : data,
           ...
         }]
 });
```

After this in controller do this

The code is pasted in the jsbin http://jsbin.com/vekacayirugu/16/edit

This kind of formatting will work for you.
reference: http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/

Comment: I've did what you posted (moving all content of series from controller to model and using data) then i did in controller "series: function () {this.get('model')}.on('init')" but it's still the same as before, empty chart without any data

Comment: you don't have to do any of that now, the this.model will the data in your required format, which is returned from router to the controller. You can directly use that data in your template to check. See my answer above.

Comment: exactly the same with "series: this.model" , maybe i will do it in jsbin ? so you can see it more clearly

Comment: if you want to access that data inside your controller, you do this.  App.CardsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({ actions: {   series: function(){ return this.get('model');} } });   that will work.

Comment: Nope, exactly the same as before. Chart still without data.

Comment: you did on('init') on series function as well?

Comment: What exactly does the chart need?

Comment: not in begining but i did now and it's still the same, i think accessing data is not a problem but it should pass to series only 2 arrays and i think it's passing whole model object with arrays and ember specific objects, or am i wrong?

Comment: it is converting the array object to ember object, you can use toJSON() method.

Comment: this is exactly this chart, click on view options to see exact code and what it needs http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/area

Comment: Were you able to display the data correctly in the console.

Comment: if you want to use jquery, what you can do is Ember.$('#container').highcharts('StockChart',YOUROBJECT); Trigger this action programmatically from your handlebars.

Comment: i have something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Lepxdgwu/1/   in html there is template that i am compiling , i have included in ajax call sample data from highcharts example demo

Comment: i couldn't get your code running on jsfiddle, but from what i see, in your component,even though you are passing chartoptions, then again you are initializing chartoptions as null, so no data is passed to chart. create another property with null in your component. I think that is the error.

Comment: if this is not the case, i will look into your code tomorrow, goodnight

Comment: data for chart is in selectedSeries not in chartoptions. it didn't work becasue as i told you i am precompiling template (this what you have in html on jsfidle) and then include it as js file. If chartoptions would be null then it would not work in situation with manual data in my question. It's the main thing, as you can see with manually entered data all works fine as i showed in my question.

Comment: This is my last try today, try my new answer to the controller

Comment: I added what you posted, still the same. Maybe this will help, in toggleChart function  inside controller i did console.log(this.model); and this is the result http://i.imgur.com/IgGAQk0.png

Comment: Hm i think i know what you are trying to do, promise is not fullfiled that's why we get problems, i can access property of model from some action in controller and output it in console but when i try to get the same property as our series data then i get that it's undefined

Comment: I've added working example without getting JSON, data is set manually that's why it works http://jsbin.com/vekacayirugu/1/edit

Comment: dynamic properties in controller should always be computed, http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/

Comment: This works for sure: "series: function() {
    return [
        { name: 'test', type: 'area', data: this.get('model') }
}.property('model')" I didn't try your solution but it does the same i assume, that's why i picked your anwser too, thx!